# How to get the label column from a table which is converted by a matrix which is obtained by the pivot function?

Tags: dolphindb

I get the matrix by the function pivot, then I transfer it into a table by the function table. I find the table lost the label column. How to save the label column in this table?

The example codes are shown as below:

```py
syms=`600300`600400`600500$SYMBOL
sym=syms[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
time=09:40:00+1 30 65 90 130 185 195 10 40 90 140 160 190 200 5 45 80 140 170 190 210
price=172.12 170.32 172.25 172. 175.1 174.85 174.5 36.45 36.15 36.3 35.9 36.5 37.15 36.9 40.1 40.2 40.25 40.15 40.1 40.05 39.95
volume=100 * 10 3 7 8 25 6 10 4 5 1 2 8 6 10 2 2 5 5 4 4 3
t1=table(sym, time, price, volume);
stockprice=pivot(wavg, [t1.price, t1.volume], minute(t1.time), t1.sym)
stockprice.round(2);
```

I get the data in stockprice

| label | 600300 | 600400 | 600500 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09:40m | 171.7 | 36.28 | 40.15 |
| 09:41m | 172.41 | 36.3 | 40.25 |
| 09:42m | 175.1 | 36.38 | 40.13 |
| 09:43m | 174.63 | 36.99 | 40.01 |

After I transfer it by the function table, the label column is missing：

```py
table(stockprice)
```

| col600300 | col600400 | col600500 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 171.7046 | 36.2833 | 40.15 |
| 172.41 | 36.3 | 40.25 |
| 175.1 | 36.38 | 40.1278 |
| 174.6312 | 36.9937 | 40.0071 |

Answer (score 0):

Use [rowNames()](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/r/rowNames.html) to get the labels of the table

```py
t2=table(stockprice)
t2[`label]=stockprice.rowNames()
```

use [reorderColumns()](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/CommandsReferences/reorderColumns!.html) to put the label at the last column

```py
t2.reorderColumns!(`label join t2.colNames()[:t2.colNames().size()-1])
```